# How to check two things in user input

Tags: python, user-input

I would like to check if my option string and my option string int are equal to BOTH values D and D. Does not pair with them both.

```
if option + option_2 == "D" and "D":
    rate = r()
    time = t()
    distance = velocity * time
    print (f"The distance traveled is {distance} meters")
    exit()`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following condition instead:

```
if option == option_2 == "D":
```